# REST return Response.temporaryRedirect - Redirect was blocked for CORS request

Tags: java, rest, response

I have the following in REST Java Server side, but I am getting
`Redirect was blocked for CORS request`

How to fix this?

```
@POST
    @Path("/details")
    public void findDetails(@FormParam("productName")
        String productName, @Context
        HttpServletRequest request, @Context
        HttpServletResponse response) {
        URI location = new java.net.URI("http://www.google.com");


            if (productName != null) {
                return Response.temporaryRedirect(location).build();                    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
productName != null
```

be

```
userid != null
```

Or rename to

```
@FormParam("productName") String productName
```